# What is this: L"DLGCTRL_"L#dialog_control_id

Tags: c++, string, literals, suffix

I've found this in some C++_11 code:

`L"DLGCTRL_"L#dialog_control_id`

What is a "L#" here? There is no # operator or concatenation so.
Yes, there is nothing between the " and the L. How can be this allowed?

I get the error:

> error C3688: invalid literal suffix 'L'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""L' not found

I have Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 on Windows 10.
It compiles normally on C++98 or 00

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain what you mean by "compiles normally on C++98 or 00".  C++98 is a language standard, not a compiler

Answer (score 2):

I assume this occurs inside a preprocessor macro otherwise the question makes no sense at all, e.g.:

```
#define X(dialog_control_id)  L"DLGCTRL_"L#dialog_control_id
```

where it is intended that `X(foo)` expands to `L"DLGCTRL_foo"`.

---

The code *should* be:

```
#define X(dialog_control_id)  L"DLGCTRL_" #dialog_control_id
```

There are several problems in the original code:

- `L#` is not allowed in ISO C++, it is an extension of the Microsoft preprocessor to produce a wide string literal.
- In the C++11 preprocessor, a letter directly after a closing quote (without whitespace in between) is tokenized as a user-defined string literal.
- The last `L` was never necessary anyway, because a wide string literal can be concatenated with a narrow string literal (producing a wide string literal)

Comment: I was wondering what this `L` is too.  Clearly part of MSFT's Embrace, Extend, Extinguish strategy.

Comment: @J.Doe the first `L` is part of Standard C++, it means the string literal is an array of `const wchar_t`. The combination `L#` is the Microsoft extension